# How to gray out a dynamic menu in prime react

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, primereact

I am populating a menu in react which is coming form backend . I am using react route to navigate them.I want to gray out one of them while they will populate in the screen.I have used two css class one is banking-supplies-content which is basically doing the formatting and i am also trying to apply the css disable-link
to disable the pointer in the menu i want to disable , but it's not working for me. Below is the code

```
return (
<div className="banking-supplies-content">
   <HashRouter>
    <Route 
    exact path="/retail-banking"
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/journal"
      component={BankingSuppliesJournalListing}
    />
    <Route exact path="/report" component={BankingSuppliesReport} />
    <Route exact path="/invoiceSearch" component={LocationInvoiceSummarySearch} />
   <div className="disable-link">
   <Route exact path="/invoiceCreate"/>
   </div>           
    {/* <Route exact path="/" component={BankingSuppliesHome} /> */}
  </HashRouter>
  <ShowSpinner showSpinner={bankingSuppliesContextReference.showSpinner} />
  
</div>
  );
};
```

css i have used

```
.banking-supplies-content {
  margin: 20px;
}
.disable-link{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

I am using the disable property to gray it out but , its not working.

[image]

Comment: Add primereact `Menu` items code

Comment: Can you please edit my code

Comment: you need to disable the Link not the Route

Comment: @Apostolos how i will do it ? can you please edit my code ?

Comment: @Apostolos i have edited my code , can you please check once ?

Comment: can you post the code for your menu links too?

Comment: @Apptolos menu code is already there